# How to add another column in an already existing dataframe performing a simple task

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I have a sample spreadsheet which contains the name of an item,its price and a url
I have to create a dataframe which adds another column named index - which compares the integer value obtained from the corresponding url in URL column to the price in the price column and shows whether is less/more than the price column

for eg

```
name     price     url
egg       2        www.xyz/1-ed  
ham       34       www.xyz/2-ed
```

the url contains another price ,
example for egg its 4 and ham its 32

so the output should be:

```
name      price     url            index
egg        2        www.xyz/1-ed    less/n   
ham        34       www.xyz/2-ed    more
```

obviously the real code contains more than 300 entries,so i have to apply it to that.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import time
    from smtplib import SMTP
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import requests
    import re


    data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\sahay\Desktop\python\priceforeca1.csv')
    df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['rates','URL'])

    print(df)
```

This is just a small part of the whole code. I am unable to get past this step.

Thanks for helping a noob out!

Answer (score 0):

You can first extract the url column from the dataframe.

```
urls= df["url"]
```

Then you will need to access each url and parse the html page and obtain the price. You can use beautiful soup to achieve this. But more on this can be suggested only after knowing the html structure of the page.

You can then append the calculated prices to the dataframe as pricesFromUrl. On this data frame you can apply a function which checks whether the price column is more or less than the priceFromUrl column and create a new column named index.

Sample snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

def getMoreOrLess(price, priceFromUrl):
    result="equal"
    if price<priceFromUrl:
        result="less"
    elif price>priceFromUrl:
        result="more"
    return result

table = {'name': ['egg','ham'],
        'price': [2,34],
        'url':['www.xyz/1-ed','www.xyz/2-ed']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns = ['name','price','url'])
urls= df["url"]
price=[]
for url in urls:
    # Do the beautiful soup code to extract price here and append to price
    #Let us say price = [4,32]
    price=[4,32]

df['priceFromUrl'] = price
df['index'] = df.apply(lambda x: getMoreOrLess(x['price'], x['priceFromUrl']), axis=1)
df=df.drop(columns='priceFromUrl')  #You can delete the column later
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is use the `apply()` function of pandas.

Here's what you need to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
# Function to check if url digit is greater, less or equal to the price
def checkForIndex(price,url):
    match=re.findall(r'(\d+)',url)
    if(int(match[0])>price):
        return 'more'
    elif(int(match[0])<price):
        return 'less'
    else:
        return 'equal'   
# Making sample data for dataframe.
d={'Price':[2,34,4,3,67],'url':['www.xyz/1-ed','www.xyz/2-ed','www.xyz/4-ed','www.xyz/5-ed','www.xyz/66-ed']}
# Making dataframe
dataFrame= pd.DataFrame(data=d)
# Making a new column based on conditions of ither columns.
dataFrame['index']=dataFrame.apply(lambda x: checkForIndex(x.Price, x.url), axis=1)
# Printing the dataframe.
print(dataFrame)
```

Output:

```
   Price            url  index
0      2   www.xyz/1-ed   less
1     34   www.xyz/2-ed   less
2      4   www.xyz/4-ed  equal
3      3   www.xyz/5-ed   more
4     67  www.xyz/66-ed   less
```

Here's some links for further reading:

- [apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)
- [Regex](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/regex#re.search)

**Hope this helps, cheers!**